# Inserting rows in existing select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Id    ProductionLineCode    JobCode ProductionHour  TargetEfficiency
211572  000001         J0000013856        1               40.00
211683  000001         J0000013856        2               40.00
211859  000001         J0000013856        4               40.00
211574  000002         J0000014107(C)     1                0.00
211688  000002         J0000014107(C)     2                0.00
211776  000002         J0000014107(C)     3                0.00
211861  000002         J0000014107(C)     4                0.00
```

But I want output like this-

```
 ID     ProductionLineCode  JobCode      Hours   TargetEfficiency
211572  000001              J0000013856     1          40.00
211683  000001              J0000013856     2          40.00
    0   000001              J0000013856     3           NULL
211859  000001              J0000013856     4          40.00
    0   000001              J0000013856     6           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856     7           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856     8           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856     9           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    10           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    11           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    12           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    13           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    14           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    15           NULL
    0   000001              J0000013856    16           NULL
```

means there should be 16 rows for hours and the rest will be null for non existing values.

How can it can be done without Joining?

- List item

Comment: You should **properly and cleanly** format your sample data - this is just a huge mess right now ....

Comment: outer join with a help table containing the values 1 to16.

Comment: Data & result don't match at all.

Comment: They don't even have the same headers!

Comment: "without Joining" - why? It's the right tool for the case.

Comment: May we ask why you wanna avoid joins? Because each alternative without them has its own problem, and there's probably a way of join that won't cause you whatever it is you wanna avoid.

Comment: @KtX2SkD The Real Data are huge. Joining will make the query less efficient and time consuming I guess.

Comment: More time consuming yes, but by 1 nanosecond or 1 gigayear? I recommend trying the most intuitive (*join*), then improve/reconsider if there's a problem.

Comment: About the task itself, for this mock data, will it need to add 19 records? I'm counting hours 5 to 12, plus hour 3, for `000001-J0000013856`, then hours 5 to 12 for `000002-J0000014107(C)`, correct?

Comment: @KtX2SkD  Yes right. For 000001-J0000013856 5 to 12 and 3 and so on..

Comment: Sorry, best I can think of (*without **any** join*) is some crazy cursor/loop with some buffer table, then end with a `UNION`, which is most certainly a performance massacre let alone the time to design. Then again, you said real data is huge, doesn't that mean the output will be more huge? How then can you use it usefully? Any news on join test btw?